# Grafana - Load dynamic metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a dynamic API that generates endpoints based on user preferences, I'm currently integrating Grafana, and I am struggling to get this graph to work:

`app_{endpoint}_{function}_calls_total`

`{endpoint}` and `{function}` are dynamic, they can be whatever the user set it to be. For example:

```
app_BillingController_getVAT_calls_total
app_UserController_verifyEmail_calls_total
app_UserController_resetPassword_calls_total
...
```

How could Grafana load these as a Time series? The data is exported through Prometheus with the Open-telemetry library.

I've tried other approaches found on SO, but none of them really did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
sum({__name__=~"app_.*._.*._calls_total"}) by (__name__)
```